# Set date to tbd if it is a specific date

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datetime, jqgrid

I tried looking around the site to see if this question has been asked before, but I can't seem to find anything about it. So I am using mvc and have a controller page that reads data that from a sqlserver database to display them in a view which contains a jqgrid.

My question is how do you take a specific datetime value, "1900-01-01 00:00:00.00" and have it displayed as tbd?

this is my code for the two datetime columns:

```
schedule.EstimatedQAStartDate = (!reader.IsDBNull(4)) ? reader.GetDateTime(4) : (DateTime?)null; 
schedule.EstimatedorProjectedReleaseDate = (!reader.IsDBNull(5)) ? reader.GetDateTime(5) : (DateTime?)null;
```

Answer (score 0):

The jqGrid solution to this would be to have a formatter for the date column as follows

Here is also a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/adgptkvj/292/) sample I created for you.

```
function formatDate(cellValue, options, rowObject) {
        if(cellValue=="1900-01-01 00:00:00.00")
               return "tbd";
               else
               return cellValue;
            };

            "use strict";
            var mydata = [
                    {id:"1", DocGroupName: "2", Date: "1900-01-01 00:00:00.00", Mandatory: "Yes"},
                    {id:"2", DocGroupName: "6", Date: "2005-03-02 05:00:00.00", Mandatory: "No"},
                    {id:"3", DocGroupName: "6", Date: "2016-08-05 08:40:00.00", Mandatory: "No"},
                ];
            $("#list").jqGrid({


                //url:'php.scripts/customers.get.php',
                //datatype: 'xml',
                //mtype: 'POST',
                datatype: "local",
                data: mydata,
                height: "auto",

                colModel :[
                    {name:'id', index:'id', width:55},
                    {name:'DocGroupName',  width:90},
                    {name:'Date', formatter:formatDate, width:90, editable: true },
                    {name:'Mandatory', index:'Mandatory', width:90, editable: true}

                ],
                pager: '#pager',
                rowNum:10,
                rowList:[10,20,30],
                sortname: 'idcustomers',
                sortorder: 'asc',
                viewrecords: true,
                gridview: true,
                caption: 'Customers',
                cellEdit: true,
                cellsubmit: 'clientArray',
                afterSaveCell: function(rowid,name,val,iRow,iCol) {
                    if(name=='DocGroupName')
                  {
                  var row = $('#list').jqGrid('getRowData',currentRow);     
                   row.DocList='';
                   var row = $('#list').jqGrid('setRowData',currentRow,row);       
                   }
                },
                beforeSaveCell: function(rowid,name,val,iRow,iCol) {
                 // var row = $("#list").getRowData(rowid);
                   var row = $('#list').jqGrid('getRowData',rowid);
                   currentRow= rowid;

                },

            });
```